# How to send a JMS message from JBOSS Fuse to Weblogic JMS

Tags: java, jboss, jms, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to send a message from Active-MQ to Weblogic. 
I have created JMS bridge like below:

```
<jmsBridgeConnectors>     
 <jmsQueueConnector name="JreportRequestBridge-Inbound" jndiOutboundTemplate="#remoteJndi"outboundQueueConnectionFactoryName="jms/ConnectionFactory"
    localQueueConnectionFactory="#activemqConnectionFactory">        
            <inboundQueueBridges>          
                <inboundQueueBridge inboundQueueName="RequestQueue"/></inboundQueueBridges>      
            </jmsQueueConnector>    
        </jmsBridgeConnectors>
<bean id="remoteJndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">        
        <property name="environment">                
            <props>                        
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://host:port</prop>                
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now when I am trying to create the Brokerservice using the destination url I am getting exception as below:

```
java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [t3]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:25)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:171)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.bind(TransportFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:1348)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.addConnector(BrokerService.java:163)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.addConnector(BrokerService.java:153)
    at test.oas.Server.<init>(Server.java:32)
    at test.oas.Server.main(Server.java:99)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/t3
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.doFindFactoryProperies(FactoryFinder.java:90)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:47)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:167)
    ... 6 more
```

Code to create the BrokerService:

```
try {            
            //This message broker is embedded            
            BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();            
            broker.setPersistent(false);            
            broker.setUseJmx(false);            
            broker.addConnector(messageBrokerUrl);            
            broker.start();       
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();      
                }
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? My suspicion is some missing JAR from the classpath but I'm not sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as Alan mentioned in the comment, this is because ActiveMQ needs the "jms" driver to be able to talk to Weblogic.

In weblogic 11g (10.3.6), you need to take the library `wlthint3client.jar` and put it in the lib folder inside ActiveMQ. This is the *weblogic t3 thin client*, which allows to connect to it using the *t3* protocol.